# How to dynamically load ion-options from array?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a service to load and save templates and want that when I click the ion-select the options are dynamically loaded so that every saved template is an option instead of hardcoded options.

I tried using an NgFor and creating an instance of the service that handles the templates in the JS file.

Here is the HTML code

````
```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Load template</ion-label>
        <ion-select>
            <ion-option *ngFor = "let template of templates;">
                {{templates}}
            </ion-option>
        </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```
````

Here's the template service code

````
```
export class TemplateService {
    public templates: Template[] = [];
...
getAllTemplates(): Template[] {
    return this.templates;
}
```
````

Here's the JS code

````
```
export class NewTransactionPage {
    templates: Template[];
...
constructor(public templateServicerino: TemplateService) {
    this.templates = this.templateServicerino.getAllTemplates();
```
````

I get an error saying "Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[NewTransactionPage -> TemplateService: StaticInjectorError(Platform:core)[NewTransactionPage -> TemplateService: NullInjectorError: No provider for Template Service!"

Comment: you have a typo in your code it is `*ngFor` not `ngfor.`

Comment: It looks like you forgot to declare TemplateService in your app.module, or maybe one of TemplateServices own dependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the service as provider. One way to do it is to use the annotation like this.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class TemplateService {//body}
```

Comment: Thank you, that solved the service issue, however there's something that's not clear to me, I copied this format from the internet  <ion-option *ngFor = "let template of templates;"> . there's no variable called "template" neither in my JS file nor in the HTML file, is that "template of templates"just convention ? other examples I have seen are like "car of cars"

Comment: `let template of templates`, means you are defining `template`, `let template` is similar to `var template`. `of` keyword gets one item at a time from `templates` array to `template` variable and the loop repeats until all items are done.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of